# UIImageView - rotate in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, rotation, uiimage

I have `UIScrollView` that handles for `image zoomimg`.

`UIImageView` is `resized` to fit `UIScrollView` (in correct ratio) and centered.

Zooming works perfect (standart code), but when rotating, I need to fix `imageview` so the `contentOffset` move in new dimensions. If I recalculate image size based on new rotated dimensions, it doesn't work in correct way.

I need to update `minimum zoom` to `fit image` to `UIScrollView` (I use it for `cropping`)

I've tried everything and no correct results.

Thank you for any advice!

```c
- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image {
    [self setDelegate:self];

    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    [self fixToImageSize];
    [self centerImage];
}
#pragma mark Image

- (void)centerImage {
    CGFloat offsetX = (self.bounds.size.width > self.contentSize.width)?
    (self.bounds.size.width - self.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = (self.bounds.size.height > self.contentSize.height)?
    (self.bounds.size.height - self.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    self.zoomContainer.center = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                        self.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
}

- (void)fixToImageSize {
    [self fixToImageSize:YES];
}

- (void)fixToImageSize:(BOOL)setZoomToMinZoom {
    float height    =   size.height;
float width     =   size.width;


// resize image to fix max scrollview bounds
if (width > bounds.size.width) {
    width   = bounds.size.width;
    height  = bounds.size.width / (size.width / size.height);
}

if (height > bounds.size.height) {
    height  = bounds.size.height;
    width   = bounds.size.height / (size.height / size.width);
}

CGRect imageSize    = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);


    [self fixImageToSize:imageSize.size];

    if (_resizeScrollViewToImage) {
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, imageSize.size.width, imageSize.size.height)];
    } else if (!self.fillRectWithColor){
        [self fixImageZoom:setZoomToMinZoom andSize:imageSize.size];
    }
}

- (void)fixImageToSize:(CGSize)imageSize {
    [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
    [self.zoomContainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
}

- (void)fixImageZoom:(BOOL)setZoomToMinZoom  andSize:(CGSize)imageSize {
    float zoomOnHeight  = self.bounds.size.height / imageSize.height;
    float zoomOnWidth   = self.bounds.size.width / imageSize.width;
    float zoom          = 1;

    if (zoomOnHeight < 1) {
        zoomOnHeight *= -1;
    }

    if (zoomOnWidth < 1) {
        zoomOnWidth *= -1;
    }

    if (zoomOnHeight > zoomOnWidth) {
        zoom            = zoomOnHeight;
    } else {
        zoom            = zoomOnWidth;
    }

    NSLog(@"Zoom on height %f",zoom);

    [self setMinimumZoomScale:zoom];

    if (setZoomToMinZoom && self.zoomScale < zoom) {
        [self setZoomScale:zoom];
    }
}

- (void)rotateImageToRight {
    if (_rotateDegrees >= 360) {
        _rotateDegrees  = 0;
    }
    _rotateDegrees += 90;

    //UIImage *newImage = [self.imageView.image rotateToDegrees:_rotateDegrees];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(_rotateDegrees));
    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.imageView.transform = transform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


        CGSize rotatedSize  = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(self.imageView.image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(_rotateDegrees)));

        if (rotatedSize.width < 0) {
            rotatedSize.width *= -1;
        }
        if (rotatedSize.height < 0) {
            rotatedSize.height *= -1;
        }

        NSLog(@"Transformed %@",NSStringFromCGSize(rotatedSize));
        float height    =   rotatedSize.height;
        float width     =   rotatedSize.width;


        // resize image to fix max scrollview bounds
        if (width > bounds.size.width) {
            width   = bounds.size.width;
            height  = bounds.size.width / (rotatedSize.width / rotatedSize.height);
        }

        if (height > bounds.size.height) {
            height  = bounds.size.height;
            width   = bounds.size.height / (rotatedSize.height / rotatedSize.width);
        }

rotatedSize    = CGSizeMake(width, height);

        NSLog(@"Transformed %@",NSStringFromCGSize(rotatedSize));

        [self.zoomContainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, rotatedSize.width, rotatedSize.height)];
        [self fixImageZoom:YES andSize:rotatedSize];

        [self centerImage];
    }];    
}


#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.zoomContainer;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    [self centerImage];
    if (self.onZoom) {
        self.onZoom(self);
    }
}
```